# How to use event.preventDefault() when function have arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, preventdefault

i have a code like this:

```
const upListCandy = (candy) => {
      /* How i add event.preventDefault() and it word*/
      axios.post("example.com", {
         candyName: candy.name
       }).then().catch()
    }
```

here is my button:

```
dataCandy?.map((item, index) => {
   return(
      <div key={index}>
        <button onClick = {() => upListCandy(item)}>{item.name}</button>
      </div>
    )   
 })
```

And my question is how add parameter of event then event.preventDefault() work?

Comment: Why do you need to preventDefault? It's just a button. Maybe add `type="button"` to it to fully define it but even that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, method of @Andy work without preventDefault,(), thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your onclick like so

```
<button onClick = {(e) => upListCandy(item,e)}>{item.name}</button>
```

and then

```
const upListCandy = (candy,event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      axios.post("example.com", {
         candyName: candy.name
       }).then().catch()
    }
```

Comment: Was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change it like this

```
dataCandy?.map((item, index) => {
   return(
      <div key={index}>
        <button onClick = {(e) => upListCandy(e,item)}>{item.name}</button>
      </div>
    )   
 })
```

```
const upListCandy = (e,ceandy) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      axios.post("example.com", {
         candyName: candy.name
       }).then().catch()
    }
```